# Does anybody know how to write an expression in R that counts NA values and valid values for a dataframe?

Tags: r

One hint is that you will use `table()` and `is.na`

For this expression, there are specific values in one column that you are trying to find the `NA` count/total.

Example:

```
team    color   state    div
  1       R       NY      1
  2       G       WI      1
  3       P       ND      2
  4       O       CO      2
  5       B       TX      1
  6       NA      MI      2
  7       Y       CA      1
  8       V       NA      2
```

Could you please help me write an expression that will specifically count `NA` and valid values by `div` (`1` and `2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `data.table` by converting the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'div', we `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), convert to a logical vector with `is.na` and count the TRUE values with `sum` to get the count of NA, similarly negate (`!`) and `sum` to get the count of non NA elemeents.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, {v1 <- is.na(unlist(.SD));list(countNA = sum(v1), 
                          countNoNA = sum(!v1)) } , by = div]
#   div countNA countNoNA
#1:   1       0        12
#2:   2       2        10
```

---

Or using `table` and `is.na`, we replicate the 'div' column to make the lengths same with that of the `unlist`ed columns and apply the `table`.

```
table(df1$div[row(df1[-4])], is.na(unlist(df1[-4])))

#    FALSE TRUE
#  1    12    0
#  2    10    2
```

#### data

As the OP changed the data in the post to image, for reproducible purposes

```
df1 <- structure(list(team = 1:8, color = c("R", "G", "P", "O", "B", 
NA, "Y", "V"), state = c("NY", "WI", "ND", "CO", "TX", "MI", 
"CA", NA), div = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("team", 
"color", "state", "div"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```